# How to add trailing spaces or blanks in the report

Tags: acumatica

Apparently the report seems to explicitly trimming any trailing spaces on report fields. But I need those spaces because it's a bank feed. I got an expression something like :

```
=PadRight( [BAccount.AcctName] , 50, ' ' )
```

or

```
='    BLAH     '
```

Still no spaces

[image]

Does anyone has any tricks to achieve it ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I believe the report engine will trim all whitespace and non-printable characters.

> Does anyone has any tricks to achieve it ?

- Yes, based on assumption above; one possible trick is to append a printable Unicode character at the end of the string that renders as whitespace but isn't technically considered white space. This type of trick is very common in phishing attacks.

I choose the 'Braille Pattern Blank' character which renders like a space character but isn't considered whitespace.
Reference:
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2800

You can copy it directly from character box in link above (highlighted blue):
[image]

And paste it in Acumatica report designer to append it after the blank space:
[image]

I tested this by selecting the field in report, it appended the desired spaces:
[image]